# Error while populating dropdown in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm getting following error while populating  (dropdown) using angularjs. I'm newbie to Angularjs and not able to figure out the issue here.

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null
at file:///Users/{userName}/Library/Application%20Support/extensions/com.example.app/lib/angular.min.js:143:330
at r (file:///Users/{userName}/Library/Application%20Support/extensions/com.example.app/lib/angular.min.js:7:332)
at r.after (file:///Users/{userName}/Library/Application%20Support/extensions/com.example.app/lib/angular.min.js:143:305)
at Object.S.(anonymous function) [as after] (file:///Users/{userName}/Library/Application%20Support/extensions/com.example.app/lib/angular.min.js:145:4)
at h [as $render] (file:///Users/{userName}/Library/Application%20Support/extensions/com.example.app/lib/angular.min.js:201:442)
at Object.<anonymous> (file:///Users/{userName}/Library/Application%20Support/extensions/com.example.app/lib/angular.min.js:182:22)
at g.$digest (file:///Users/{userName}/Library/Application%20Support/extensions/com.example.app/lib/angular.min.js:102:56)
at g.$apply (file:///Users/{userName}/Library/Application%20Support/extensions/com.example.app/lib/angular.min.js:105:7)
at h (file:///Users/{userName}/Library/Application%20Support/extensions/com.example.app/lib/angular.min.js:68:175)
at B (file:///Users/{userName}/Library/Application%20Support/extensions/com.example.app/lib/angular.min.js:72:215)
```

Here is my html look like:

```
<select id="promoDropDown" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="promo as promo.promoId for promo in promoCollection"></select>
```

Here is my controller method look like. I get the data using $http:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
```

mainApp.controller("PromoList", ['$scope','$http', 'modelSerivce', 'promoCollectionService', function ($scope, $http, modelSerivce, promoCollectionService){
    var serviceURL = modelSerivce.serviceURL();

```
serviceURL.then(function(configData) {  // this is only run after $http completes

    $http.post(SERVICE_URL + "GetPromoInfo", {enumPromoType:1, enumRequestSource:2}).
    success(function(data) {
        var promoCollectionData = promoCollectionService.getPromoCollection(data);
        promoCollectionData.then(function(promoCollection){
            $scope.promoCollection = promoCollection;
            $scope.selectedItem = $scope.promoCollection[0];

            $scope.removeSelectedSpreads = function(promoInfoObject){                    
                 angular.forEach(promoInfoObject.spreadList, function(spreadObject){
                     if(spreadObject.isSelected) spreadObject.isSelected = false;
                 });
                // promoInfoObject.allSelected = false;
            };

            $scope.promoChangeHandler = function(){

            };

        }, function(reason){alert("Failed in controller: " + reason);});
    }).
    error(function(data, status){
        $scope.data = data || "Request Failed";
        $scope.status = status;
        //console.log("Error: Unable to fetch info Data: "+ data + " status: "+status);
    });
});}]);
```

**EDIT:**
I do not get this error if I bind the data with other way like:

```
<select name="promoId" ng-model="selectedItem">
                    <option ng:repeat="promo in promoCollection" value="{{promo.promoId}}">{{promo.promoId}}</option>
                </select>
```

But then I get empty item selected on top of dropdown.

**Update:** I figured out issue partly. I should be using default  to handle null value in dropdown. But I don't have requirement to add that. So still looking out someway to deal with null value in dropdown. here is how can we avoid above given error:

```
<select id="promoDropDown" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="promo.promoId for promo in promoCollection">
                <option value="">-- choose promo date --</option>
            </select>
```

**Update:**
The issue got fixed it self when I used non-minified version of angular. I'm not sure what caused this error. But it got resolved now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: 1. Do **not** use minified code for debugging purposes. 2. Prepare a fiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks for info, yes i believe that only caused the problem.

Comment: I actually meant you should not use the minified version of Angular (or other libs) for debugging.